# How to search multiple words with javascript and Regex inside an html div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm having a problem with a search system in JavaScript and RegExp. I already have the code working on the site, but it can only fetch a word, if I type two words it does not return results.
Here is an example of the currently running search field:
https://www.apaixonadosporhistoria.com.br/ficcao
When entering the name of the author in the field the divs that do not contain this name are hidden, and only appears the div with the name.
But like I said, the problem is the words in the correct order. And I would also need to search multiple words allowing several different orders, for example:
brenda, 
vantrease brenda, 
vantrease rickman, 
brenda vantrease rickman

Below is my HTML and JavaScript code:

```html
<input type="text" id="buscarautor" placeholder="Pesquise por autores" />

<div class="order-item autoritem">
  <a href="https://www.apaixonadosporhistoria.com.br/ficcao-autor/50/gary-jennings">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 sempaddingleft">
      <div class="bloco-externo" data-nome="gary jennings" data-qtd="5" data-ano="2016-03-22 00:43:21"  data-view="22">
        <div class="bloco">
          <div class="autor" style="background:url(https://www.apaixonadosporhistoria.com.br/img/ficcaoautor/ficcao_50_1752577805.jpg"></div>
          <div class="fundolinha"><div class="linhacresce"></div></div>
          <div class="nomeqtd"><h1>Gary Jennings<br/><small>5 livros</small></h1></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div><!-- order-item -->
```

```
if (!RegExp.escape) {
  RegExp.escape = function (s) {
    return s.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
  };
}

if ($(".autoritem").length) {
  var $rows = $('.autoritem');
  $('#buscarautor').keyup(function () {
    var regex =  new RegExp(RegExp.escape($.trim(this.value).replace(/\s+/g, ' ')), 'i')
    $rows.hide().filter(function () {
      var text = $(this).find('.bloco-externo').data('nome').replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
      return regex.test(text)
    }).show();
  });
  $('#buscarautor').val('');
}
```

Comment: brenda, vantrease brenda are they supposed to be considered as 2 different words.. I mean vantrease brenda is it supposed to be considered a match only if it matches whole word or either vantrease or Brenda

Comment: What do you expect when entering multiple words? Is an element shown if it includes one of the words, all the words in the same order or all the words negating the word order?

Comment: What does this mean `if (!RegExp.escape) ` ? Does 'escape` hold a pointer to a function ? How do you dereference it ? If you can't, why can you assign it to a function reference ? What happens if it's null and you attempt to call it ? Sounds like a bunch of HSt